# IllegalstateException

Tags: android, android-listview, illegalstateexception

I have two activities.One activity has listview and second activity has gridview..one i click from listview activity the next activity will open safly but when i press back button from emulator listacitivity will show but when i click on listactivity again it give me forceclose option and my app crash...Logcat error is there..

```
01-30 05:32:24.748: E/AndroidRuntime(998): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-30 05:32:24.748: E/AndroidRuntime(998): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(16908298, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class android.widget.ArrayAdapter)]
01-30 05:32:24.748: E/AndroidRuntime(998):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1538)
01-30 05:32:24.748: E/AndroidRuntime(998):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3513)
01-30 05:32:24.748: E/AndroidRuntime(998):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7127)
01-30 05:32:24.748: E/AndroidRuntime(998):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2170)
01-30 05:32:24.748: E/AndroidRuntime(998):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1905)
01-30 05:32:24.748: E/AndroidRuntime(998):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
01-30 05:32:24.748: E/AndroidRuntime(998):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
01-30 05:32:24.748: E/AndroidRuntime(998):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
01-30 05:32:24.748: E/AndroidRuntime(998):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
01-30 05:32:24.748: E/AndroidRuntime(998):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
01-30 05:32:24.748: E/AndroidRuntime(998):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
01-30 05:32:24.748: E/AndroidRuntime(998):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1925)
01-30 05:32:24.748: E/AndroidRuntime(998):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1379)
01-30 05:32:24.748: E/AndroidRuntime(998):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2396)
01-30 05:32:24.748: E/AndroidRuntime(998):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1873)
```

Comment: Reread the error report ***The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread.***.

Comment: i don't know how to remove this..

Comment: Without code we cant imagine??

Answer (score 0):

Without the code, It is quite difficult to say what might be wrong. but the most possible solution I can think of is,

I think you are performing some computations in the second Activity, which are modifying the contents that are being displayed in the List Activity.

When you open `second activity`, just `finish()` the `first Activity` and on pressing back button(Override the `onBackPressed()`) from the second Activity create a new `Intent` to open the first activity.

Let me know if you want assistance on how to override the `onBackPressed()` function.

Comment: I have posted my Code as well

Comment: my code is very much long..Stackoverflow does't allow me to post such a long code

Comment: how can i post it...When ever i try its give me error...In comments its to long..In edit mode its said give deteal of your code